# Disable records removal of standard table through maintenance view

Tags: abap, sap-data-dictionary

There is a standard table T513 and customer master data table T7SK13, which is modified by customer using maintenance view V_T7SK13, with following tables/join conditions:

[image: A]

Is there a possibility to somehow disable removal of records from international table T513, but still allowing to add new records there?

I can remove the delete button for maintenance view using `excl_cua_funct` parameter of function `view_maintenance_call`, but this would also disable removal of records from customer table T7SK13, which still needs to work.

Answer (score 3):

You may find this useful. You add code that is called by
generated views that is called at particular events.
Like before delete. Event 03.
See the **View V_TVIMF**

You can use mod assistant to add a form routine.
Or add it use implicit enhancements. If that makes people feel better. ;)

Sm30 v_tvimf

[image: sm30 V_TVIMF]
V_t7sk13

[image: V_T7SK13]

[image: Add a new]

[image: Add a method to the existing ls3kf01]

[image: Sexy Mod]

Comment: Using an implicit enhancement definitely makes me feel better. :)

Comment: Seems great, did not know about such a functionality, thanks a lot. Although I'm not sure whether this can solve our issue, we need to update only T7SK13, and keep T513 the same as it was before.

Comment: there are about 30 events that you can hang code behind.
Useful on your own views, but even with mod assist, or implicit enhancement in standard views. So you should add the checks you want.